# unable to set push notification sound in android

Tags: android, audio, notifications, push-notification

I have created the push notification application, I'm getting the message from GCM services but push notification sound is not working. I need to play sound when I'm getting notification.I have posted my code below anyone help me with this...

```
//receiver class//


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());

    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    generateNotification(context);

    System.out.println("received push notification");

    Toast.makeText(context,"received notification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

private void generateNotification(Context context)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*NotificationManager mBuilder=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri notificationsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    mBuilder.setSound(notificationsound);
    */
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}




package com.everest.jewellerapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService
{


  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

  public GCMNotificationIntentService() 
  {
    super("GcmIntentService");
  }

  public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
  {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) 
    {
      if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) 
      {
        sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
      }
      else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) 
      {
        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
            + extras.toString());
      } 
      else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) 
      {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          Log.i(TAG,
              "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                  + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
          try 
          {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
          } 
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
          }

        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "+ extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));



        Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
      }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
  }

  private void sendNotification(String msg) 
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("ijeweller")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setContentTitle("").setContentText("");
    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }); 
    mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000); 


    Uri notificationsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    mBuilder.setSound(notificationsound);


    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
  }
}
```

permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.everest.jewellerapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.everest.jewellerapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use the default notification sound. Maybe this will work:

```
mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
```

This worked for me, though the `setDefaults()` method does overwrite any vibration or LED light settings, so if you are wanting those as well you might have to set the sound directly. If default lights and/or vibration is fine you can bitwise OR the other static constants in `Notification`

Answer (score 1):

I use this code:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();
```

Comment: Have you set all required permissions and do you get any exceptions?