# Android push notification how to play default sound

Tags: android, push-notification, mixpanel

I'm using MixPanel to send push notification and on the custom payload I add the following code:
{"sound":"default"} the problem Is that no sound gets played when I receive the notification. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408929/unable-to-set-push-notification-sound-in-android) code will look like this.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to send notification + sound using mixpanel, you need to do the following:

- add the following code to the onCreate:

  ```
          NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
          mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
          Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
          Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
          r.play();
  ```
- Send notification from mixpanel and see it received. This will send notification on create with default sound configured on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a declaration...

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setWhen(ts)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .setContentText(message);
```

... variable constructed somewhere in your code, try this:

```
final String ringTone = "default ringtone"; // or store in preferences, and fallback to this
mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(ringTone));
```

Comment: I get an error that says "mBuilder is not initialized" If I click on the fix button Eclipse auto initialize mBuilder to null and when I run the app it crashes

Comment: I mentioned "assuming" you have it filled in somewhere. Anyway, it would look like the edited code above. Note, you have to set the title, ts, and message variables!

Comment: Right answer for me (using adapted Xamarin code). Totally forgot to check if Builder had a SetSound method! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try following code

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.appicon,
                "Notification", System.currentTimeMillis()); 
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Notification notification =
    new Notification(iconResId, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
notification.sound =
    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + soundResId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default GCMReceiver in the Mixpanel library for Android that handles incoming push notifications from Mixpanel doesn't include sounds. You'll need to write your own BroadcastReceiver to process incoming messages from Mixpanel.

You can take a look at Mixpanel's documentation for using the low level API at : https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-push-notifications#advanced - then you an apply the advice from the other answers to do anything you'd like with your custom data payload.